# No wifi or ethernet connection after installing 14.04

Tags: wireless

I installed 14.04 to my Dell D520.  I cannot connect to either ethernet or wifi.  The icon in the upper right corner does not show any network devices.  HOw do I fix this?

Comment: Please show us the output of the following command in the terminal:
`sudo ifconfig -a` At least we'll know whether the cards are detected or not.

Comment: Here is what I got:

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.01   Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:32  errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        Tx packets:32  errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        colisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB) TX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB)

Comment: Basically it says no NIC was detected. The problem is with the drivers not with some sort of configuration. You may wish to take a look at hardware compatibility list to make sure it is supposed to work so you spare a few hours trying the impossible. You may wish to buy another Network card for that computer instead of using the one onboard...

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 1):

try this , it will solve your eth0 problem:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```

and for wifi if you are shown b43 firmware not installed on start on your Ubuntu try this :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and if any other firmware is missing try opening that site